# Discover JPA annotated classes when using Spring 3+Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, persistence

I have a web application using the Spring 3 + Hibernate JPA stack.

I would like to know if there is a way to have Hibernate to automatically discover @Entity annotated classes, so that I don't have to list them in the persistence.xml file.
My @Entity annotated classes "live" in a separate jar, located in the WEB-INF/lib of my web application.

This is a snippet from my Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mypersistence"/>
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
           <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
           <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
           <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
       </bean>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/library;create=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="app"/>
    <property name="password" value="app"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceAnnotation" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the persistence.xml file inside the jar where your entities live. Don't need to specify anything then, it works automagically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint. I was already trying to recursively scan the classpath to find those classes in jar files. :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can also specify your  @Entity annotated classes in applicationContext.xml like this

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
     <list>
        <value>com.vattikutiirf.nucleus.domain</value>
        <value>com.vattikutiirf.nucleus.domain.generated.secondtime</value>
     </list>
  </property>
```

Comment: Note that `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan` is only available in [Spring 3.1 onwards](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan(java.lang.String...))

Answer (score 2):

The separate jar files to scan for entities are specified using `<jar-file>` elements in `persistence.xml`. So, if you entities are located in `/WEB-INF/lib/entities.jar`, you need

```
<jar-file>lib/entities.jar</jar-file>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I didn't know that. Still, is there a way to have Hibernate/Spring to scan for JPA annotated classes, so my persistence.xml doesn't have to reference any jar (jar may change name, etc).

Comment: @Luciano: It looks like `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` allows you to set a custom `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor` that can add this element programmatically by calling `MutablePersistenceUnitInfo.addJarFileUrl()`.